# using JUnitEE with JBoss-IDE

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-portal, jboss-tools

Can anyone provide me with a tutorial on how to use JUnitEE with JBoss-IDE ?

thanks.

Comment: It's been 5 years since the last release of JUnitEE... surely there must be something newer?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are asking for JBoss-IDE since JunitEE is just a framework which is not dependent on the IDE. Following JunitEE how-to at http://www.junitee.org/usersguide.html seem to show all the needed info ?

Today we recommend using Arquillian for doing testing.

Comment: I'm asking this because I use JBoss-IDE and it's the least intuitive IDE i've ever used. and I've tried the tutorial at JUnitEE website, and still haven't figured out to set it up, meanwhile, i'm getting late on schedule, but I want to use TDD, so i must set it up before starting coding. thanks.